# How to get attributes from container node used to render React app?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

In an `ejs` file, I have the following:

```
<div id='app-container' csrf='<%= _csrf %>'</div>
```

In a `js` file, I render a React component using the above `div`:

```
const domContainer = document.querySelector('#app-container');
ReactDOM.render(e(Faucet), domContainer);
```

I would like to access the `csrf` attribute and pass it into the component as a prop.

I'm currently doing this by replacing the second line:

```
ReactDOM.render(e(Faucet, { 'csrf': domContainer.attributes.csrf.value }), domContainer);
```

What's the recommended way to do this? Also, is there any reason React doesn't pass attributes in as props for the top level container by default?

Comment: What's wrong with the way you did it? and why would React do that by default, I never needed html attributes inside a React component, I don't think it's common.

Comment: Just wondering if there's a better solution. I guess it's not so bad though